# Derive the Matrix Representation of the Tensor Product

Tags: tensor-products, kronecker-product

I'm stuck on the following problem regarding the relationship between the Tensor Product and the Kronecker product:
[PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xwu1.png)

How does one go about showing that the matrix representation of the tensor product is the Kronecker Product? (I believe that's what the question is asking).

I'd appreciate any insights on this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked for insights, but you've already had one:

You're right. That is what the question is asking.

You might want to ask "if I compute $s = (A \otimes B)(v_1 \otimes x_1)$, how can I write $s$ as a linear combination of the vectors $w_i \otimes y_j$?" As a first step, you might want to write $Av_1$ as a linear combination of the $w_i$s.

Comment: I'm still struggling to get the idea. Would you be able to write out the first few steps in some detail?

Comment: Sorry I timed out on the above comment: What does Avi = a1w1 + a2w2 + ... + a_i w _i give me? Do I want to write out the matrix A explicitly and do the same for B and then directly compute their tensor product?

Comment: You write "What does Avi = a1w1 + a2w2 + ... + a_i w _i give me?" and my answer is "Hunh? What are a1, a2, etc?"  (Also: please learn to use LaTeX, so we can figure out what you're trying to say.)

Comment: I'm quite familiar with LaTeX - I didn't realize that this comment section supports it. Anyways, what I meant was $A(v_j)=\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{ij}w_i, 1\leq j \leq n$ and $B(x_j)=\sum_{i=1}^{p}b_{ij}y_i, 1\leq j \leq q$. This gives me the matrix representations of A and B respectively.

From your first comment, $s = (A \otimes B)(v_1 \otimes x_1)$, which I believe is equal to $(Av_1) \otimes (Bx_1)$.

Comment: So then I have: $s=(\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{i1}w_i) \otimes (\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_{i1}y_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{p}a_{i1}b_{j1}(w_i \otimes y_j)$. So I've written $s$ as a linear combination of the vectors $w_i\otimes y_j$. I'm not sure where to go from there! What exactly does $s$ represent?

Comment: Actually I think I'm done: If we consider $v_r\otimes w_t$ with $1\leq r\leq n$, $1\leq t\leq m$, then we have: $(A\otimes B)(v_r\otimes w_t)=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{p}a_{ik}b_{jl}(w_i\otimes y_j)$, $1\leq k \leq n$, $1\leq l \leq q$. This generates all of the entries of the Kronecker product! My final question is how do I formerly explain the grouping of these entries? i.e. group all of the $a_{11}$ entries together, all of the $a_{12}$ entries together and so on. Thanks for your first suggestion my friend! I hope I haven't made any critical errors...

Comment: You've done just right. Your last question is sorta "What order do I put these things in???" Ans: It depends on the order in which you write the basis elements. I suggest $H_1 = v_1 \otimes  x_1, H_2 =  v_1 \otimes x_2, ..., H_{nq} =v_n \otimes x_q$, and a similar order for $K_1 = w_1 \otimes y_1, \ldots, K_{mp}= w_m \otimes y_p$. Then the $i,j$ entry of the matrix for $A \otimes B$, call it $C_{ij}$ is the coefficient of $K_i$ in the expression for $A\otimes B$ applied to $H_j$ (or I might have that backwards). That coeff is, as you've see, a product of little $a$s and $bs$. Nice work!

Comment: BTW, the subsecripts on $H$ in the prior remark are single indices that run from $1$ to $n \cdot q$, just to be clear. $H_{nq}$ looks a lot like a double-index, doesn't it?

Comment: Fantastic that makes total sense! Also, let me just correct a typo I made in my last comment. The matrix rep. is given by: $(A\otimes B)(v_r\otimes x_t)=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{p}a_{ik}b_{jl}(w_i\otimes y_j)$. Cheers!